# Assigning values to array positions

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var numbers = [time1, time2, time3];

    // Sorting the numbers array simply using the sort method
    numbers.sort(); // Sorts numbers array
    document.write(numbers + "<hr>"); // Outputs: 1,12,15,3,5,7,9
    /* Sorting the numbers array numerically in ascending order
    using the sort method and a compare function */
    numbers.sort(function(a, b){
        return a - b;
    });
    
    document.write(numbers); // Outputs: 1,3,5,7,9,12,15
    
}
```

This is my code at the moment. It reads three values defined elsewhere at runtime and puts them into the correct numerical order. How could I remove a value if it was equal to 0 and then assigning states to each number? Basically a first, second, and third basis for a race state.

Comment: What's "state"?

Comment: And what's a race state?

Comment: I was wondering about it too

Comment: This could help you with removing the appropriate value - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5767325/how-can-i-remove-a-specific-item-from-an-array

Comment: numbers = numbers.sort((a, b)=> a - b).filter(e => e != 0);  after sortimng you can filter the result

Comment: Note: The reason why your 1st sort (referring to *Sorting the numbers array simply using the sort method*) doesn't work as expected is because they are apparently strings

Comment: I don'y mean Race state within any form of programming. I meant to say the states of a race meaning coming first second and third due to what time you got. Sorry that's my mistake.